# Book Publication Data Page

Tags: single-word-requests, books

In an English-language book, we conventionally have, among the first few pages, a page displaying essential data concerning the book: Library of Congress Cataloguing Data, various credits, publication date/location, copyright and other legal information, etc.

What is this page called? Do we have a specific term for it?

EDIT: in my research, I found this described as *metadata*. Would it be appropriate to call it the *metadata page*?

Comment: Generally it's called the copyright page, because copyright is a legal requirement; all those first few pages together are called generically _Front Matter_.

Comment: I agree with John Lawler that these first pages are called *Front Matter.* I would not call them *metadata*. Nobody would know what you're talking about. You might find this article helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page in question is conventionally called the *Front Matter*. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Front_matter).

(Thanks to John Lawler and JLG, q.v. comments on question.)

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard it referred to as the "copyright page," but it looks like it's also called the "[edition notice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edition_notice)."

Comment: That's also helpful; cheers